# Ordered list issue

Tags: support, markdown

I noticed a problem which appeared on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12381550/794075) from Stack Overflow. In the answer there is an ordered list, and after the first item in the list there is a 'pre' tag. For some reason, even though the list in edit mode starts with 2, it appears to start from 1.

This is the text in edit mode:

```
1. Tokenize the string. See what each symbol is. For example, the list may contain:

<pre>'(' Open parentheses
'11' Number
'+' Operator etc</pre>

2. Convert the expression to [postfix][2]...
```

And this is how I see it:

> [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change it as the following:

```
1. Tokenize the string. See what each symbol is. For example, the list may contain:

        '(' Open parantheses
        '11' Number
        '+' Operator etc

2. Convert the expression to [postfix][2]…
```

The `<pre>` part has been indented of 8 spaces.

It will be rendered as follows.

1. Tokenize the string. See what each symbol is. For example, the list may contain:

   ```
   '(' Open parantheses
   '11' Number
   '+' Operator etc
   ```
2. Convert the expression to [postfix](http://example.com)…

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a bug, it's Markdown syntax. In ordered lists, the number you write doesn't matter.

The Markdown code

```
15. this
37. is
9. a
177. test
```

gets rendered as

15. this
16. is
17. a
18. test

If you need multiple paragraphs in a single item, indent all but the first one (one to four spaces).

The Markdown code

```
1. A

 B

1. C
```

gets rendered as

1. A

   B
2. C

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this, which created the confusion.